# Screen goes blank when setting up Google account in GNOME control center. (Ubuntu 17.04)

Tags: gnome, 17.04, google-drive, gnome-control-center

I wanted to access my Google Drive locally. Found out that using the gnome control center to do this is a good idea.

So I install the control center and go to online accounts and try to add a Google Account. After entering password and hitting enter, the screen goes blank.

[Screenshot of the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9imx.png)

Answer (score 0):

This bug is listed here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/webkit2gtk/+bug/1687019?comments=all

See the various comments there on how to fix the problem. In summary:

```
start terminal
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

It should be fixed right away. No reboot required.